# Python проверка наличия в базе SQL телеграм бот

Tags: python, sql

Хочу сделать чтобы при нажатие на /start проверялось есть ли этот юзер в базе и если нету то добавлялся.Как правильно сделать?

```
    import sqlite3


    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start_message(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добрый день ' + str(message.from_user.username) + ' видео на какую тему желаете посмотреть?', reply_markup=keyboard)
        cc1 = message.from_user.username
        db = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
        cursor = db.cursor()

        query = "SELECT * FROM polls_user_name WHERE unique = '%s'"%(cc1)
        cursor.execute(query)
```

**структура базы**

--

```
CREATE TABLE "polls_user_name" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "unique" varchar(200) NOT NULL, "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL);
```

Comment: *структура базы* Это таблица. *если нету то добавлялся* Просто делать INSERT, и игнорировать ошибку дублирования, если запись имеется. Само собой, поле должно быть обложено уникальным (возможно первичным) индексом.

Comment: unique = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=200) Вы имели ввиду добавить primary_key ?

Comment: PK уже есть - это поле `id`. Cоздайте уникальный индекс по полю `unique`.

Answer (score 0):

если БД поддерживает INSERT IGNORE, то можно и без селекта (только нужно добавить уникальний ключ на 'unique'):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO polls_user_name (unique, pub_date) VALUES  ('%s', '%s')
```

2-е '%s' - 'это дата добавления;

или посчитать количество и если рано 0, то инсертить

```
select count(*) as count FROM polls_user_name WHERE unique = '%s'

если count==0

INSERT INTO polls_user_name (unique, pub_date) VALUES  ('%s', '%s')
```